# Transition smach to same final state

Tags: smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I want to execute a self transition in which the initial state is same as the final state
**STATE_A -----> STATE_A**
However, when the smach.execute() is called, it continuously executes the transition in an infinite loop.
My main main condition is that I need to do a self transition.

Please suggest any suitable techniques to do so.
Thanks and Cheers !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270361/transition-smach-to-same-final-state/) by [amarbanerjee23](https://answers.ros.org/users/30844/amarbanerjee23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2017-09-10**:
Not sure what you are trying to do. If you at the end enter STATE_A again with the same input data as the first time, wouldn't you expect the state machine execution to loop forever?

**Comment by [amarbanerjee23](https://answers.ros.org/users/30844/amarbanerjee23/) on 2017-09-12**:
Hi @knxa. The problem I am facing need to have a self transition from initial state A to final state A. But behaviour of initial state A is different to final state A. I wish to use the concept of entry and exit actions to create behaviour for transitions and not states.

Hope I was able to explain.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-12**:
I think I believe I agree with @knxa: if the behaviour is different, why are you trying to reuse the state?

**Comment by [amarbanerjee23](https://answers.ros.org/users/30844/amarbanerjee23/) on 2017-09-12**:
Hi @gvdhoorn, I see what you are saying, but I want to reuse the state but with a different action behaviour. E.g. A->B is a transition T1 having some actions, while A->A is another transition T2 with a different action. I want to associate the behaviour with the transition not the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A state represents a task being done. If the task represented by A should be performed again it makes ok sense to me to reenter A. And it makes sense that the behaviour of A might be dependent on input.

But a state is not aware of how the state was entered, whether the transition came from B or from itself or something else.
You will have to provide this difference as userdata if you need it.

Consider if A really represents the same task both in the beginning and the end.

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2017-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amarbanerjee23](https://answers.ros.org/users/30844/amarbanerjee23/) on 2017-09-13**:
Hi, @knxa,I tried doing that but still, the statemachine seems to run in an infinite loop.
However,when I try the self transition A->A in a Concurrence container,it runs only once as per requirement. Would that be a good option ? Else, could you please give an example for A->A transition in smach ?

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2017-09-13**:
I am not yet too experience with SMACH myself so take my input with caution. Unfortunately I don't have time to construct an example for you. Good luck.

**Comment by [amarbanerjee23](https://answers.ros.org/users/30844/amarbanerjee23/) on 2017-09-13**:
No problem ! Thanks for your inputs !!
It seems that Concurrent containers do not get into an infinite loop for a self transition and userdata does not help in changing behaviour of a state at different conditions.
Thanks and Cheers !!